# LightFM library install error on Sagemaker Notebook

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, amazon-sagemaker

I was using LightFM library on Sagemaker Notebook without any issue before.

However, from yesterday, I started seeing this error message and could no longer complete installation (pip install lightfm)

```
 Building wheels for collected packages: lightfm
  Building wheel for lightfm (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [176 lines of output]
      /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:775: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
...
...
...
...
      In file included from /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/include/python3.10/unicodeobject.h:1046:0,
                       from /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/include/python3.10/Python.h:83,
                       from lightfm/_lightfm_fast_openmp.c:20:
      /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:551:42: note: declared here
       Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_FromUnicode(
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lightfm

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried several suggestions I found from web, such as

pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install Cmake
pip install requests --no-dependencies

but none of these worked - still getting same error message.

How should I mitigate from this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the lightfm package installation. Have you tried installing this in another environment? This can also be dependent on the notebook kernel you are using. Can you try installing in a virtual environment as well?

Comment: working with 3.9 pytorch kernel mitigated this issue. thanks.